# Mysql - Groupby on two fields and limit row for each composite group to 1

Tags: mysql

I have attached an image of my table with data. Now this table stores all the messaging which a user sends to others and receives.
I want to display something like facebook personal messages where the latest message between the user and other users is displayed in the list and when the user clicks on that message whole thread between those two users are displayed. I have tried a lot but could not find a way to display it properly.

This table will be storing messages of all users who are friends and who are not as well. So i want to get the list of messages of only those users who have messaged me.

I am not sure if my database design is right or not ? Please help me with suggestions or help how to achieve my requirement.

---

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | is_read | message | parent_id | sent_date | is_sender_deleted | is_receiver_deleted|
```

---

```
1  |5  |4  |0  |How are you ?  |0  |2012-08-20 17:33:54    |0  |0
```

```
2  |4  |5  |0  |hiiiiiiii      |0  |2012-08-20 17:35:02    |0  |0
```

```
3  |5  |4  |0  |I am testing   |0  |2012-08-20 17:35:02    |0  |0
```

```
4  |4  |5  |0  |Helloooooo     |0  |2012-08-20 17:35:33    |0  |0
```

```
5  |5  |4  |0  |Hello's Reply  |0  |2012-08-20 17:47:41    |0  |0
```

```
8  |6  |5  |0  |Hiii...Inx here|0  |2012-08-20 18:59:18    |0  |0
```

```
9  |5  |6  |0  |Yes mate....?  |0  |2012-08-20 19:00:07    |0  |0
```

Comment: Do `is_sender_deleted` and `is_receiver_deleted` check whether the user is deleted?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's helpful in your question to show what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear about what you're trying to do. It seems you need a query that returns the latest message from each sender_id to a particular given receiver_id.

If you don't have access to an SQL client program (if you're trying to develop this in, for example, PHP or Java without an SQL client program) please obtain access to an SQL client. It will be brutally hard to develop without that.

We need to figure out which message is the latest from each sender, and how many messages the sender has sent.  This requires a summary query.  Let us assume that the message.id field is an autoincrement field, and that the latest message has the highest id.

```
     SELECT sender_id, MAX(id) id, COUNT(id) message_count
       FROM message
      WHERE receiver_id = 'receiver id to use'
        AND is_sender_deleted = 0
        AND is_receiver_deleted = 0
   GROUP BY sender_id
```

This will give us a list of the most recent messages by sender, with a count of all the messages from that sender.  See this sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caff6/1/0

Now, let's use that summary query to select the message text and other good stuff.

```
      SELECT m.sender_id, s.message_count, m.sent_date, m.message
        FROM message m
        JOIN (
               SELECT sender_id, MAX(id) id, COUNT(id) message_count
                 FROM message
                 WHERE receiver_id = 'receiver id to use'
                  AND is_sender_deleted = 0
                  AND is_receiver_deleted = 0
             GROUP BY sender_id 
             )s
          ON m.id = s.id 
    ORDER BY m.sent_date desc, m.sender_id
```

This result set presents a list, for a particular `receiver id to use`, of the number of messages from each sender, the text and time of the latest message, and the identity of the sender.  Here's a sqlfiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caff6/3/0

Retrieving all the messages from a particular sender to a particular receiver should be a simple query once you know the `receiver id to use` and `sender id to use`.

```
     SELECT *
       FROM message 
      WHERE sender_id = 'sender id to use'
        AND receiver_id = 'receiver id to use'
        AND is_sender_deleted = 0
        AND is_receiver_deleted = 0
   ORDER BY sent_date DESC
```

Comment: Sorry for vague information. Thanks for so detailed help. Suppose there are two users A,B. Now if A message then he will be sender but if he receives message from B he will be receiver. So i cannot group by sender_id or receiver_id. It will not give me all messages between A & B.
So needed to find a way where I can group by sender_id and receiver_id together, just like composite field. So I just added the two ids and this way will get unique records as required.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You can `GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id` without problems.